# How to change Webpack devServer: proxy to change dynamically from other input file or from parameters

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using Webpack to build out the js library and using web dev server to test my library.

In the webpack.config.js, I add below:

```
{
let targetProxy = 'https://xxxxx.mm.com';


if (evn === 'dev-stg') {
     targetProxy = 'https://xxxxx-stg.mm.com';
}
else {
     targetProxy = 'https://xxxxx-pre.mm.com';
}

devServer: {
            port: 4200,
            contentBase: __dirname + '/dist',
            inline: true,
            proxy: {
                '/api': {
                    target: targetProxy,
                    changeOrigin: true
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Currently this input parameters is from webpack command line:

> webpack --progress --env dev-stg

but I want to dynamically change the target address when running webpack-dev-server instead of from webpack --env parameters? Is it possible to achievie it?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a webpack plugin called [proxy-switch-plugin](https://github.com/Soundmark/proxy-switch-plugin#readme) to dynamically change the proxy.